# How to populate mongoose virtual from another referenced model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
 // define a schema
  const personSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      first: String,
      last: String
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
  },);
personSchema.virtual('fullName').
  get(function() {
    return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
    }).
  set(function(v) {
    this.name.first = v.substr(0, v.indexOf(' '));
    this.name.last = v.substr(v.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  });

  // compile our model
  const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

This is from the docs to define [#virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)

Let's have another model that has reference with Person:

```js
 const shopSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Person" },
  });
const Shop = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

Now, how to get `fullName` virtuals on shop populate `owner`. Here, the owner doesn't include `fullName`

```js
const getAllData = async () => {
     const shops = await Shop.find().populate("owner").lean();
     console.log(shops)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#:%7E:text=Using%20lean()%20bypasses%20all%20Mongoose%20features%2C%20including%20virtuals%2C%20getters/setters%2C%20and%20defaults.):

> Using lean() bypasses all Mongoose features, including virtuals, getters/setters, and defaults. If you want to use these features with lean(), you need to use the corresponding plugin.

So that, `fullName` has been removed from the returned data. The simple way for you to get `fullName` virtuals is to change your query to something like this:

```js
const getAllData = async () => {
  const shops = await Shop.find()
    .populate({
      path: 'owner',
      options: {
        lean: false
      }
    })
    .lean();
  console.log(shops);
};
```

It won't use `lean()` inside `populate` or you can disable `lean()` at all.